# Connect to a MySQL Database running in a Docker container, from another container

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have a docker-compose.yml file in which I am running airflow, everything is running ok. But I have another docker-compose.yml file for a container in which I set up a MySQL database. I want to write a pandas dataframe to that database but I am not being able.

The docker-compose for airflow is the oficial one.

**docker-compose.yml for mysql db:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mi_mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
        - '4004:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: matitorres
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testfligoo
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**Python code in airflow:**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

conn = BaseHook.get_connection('mysql')

engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{conn.login}:{conn.password}@{conn.host}:{conn.port}/{conn.schema}")

df.to_sql('testdata', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Error I am getting:

```
INFO - (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mi_mysql' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Configuration of the connection in airflow:

host: mi_mysql (the name of the mysql container)
port: 4004

I will appreciate any help :)

Comment: each docker compose will have its own network, its not accessible from the other compose, try either add the config to airflow compose or read how to configure network so the container can see each others.

Comment: if i put all together in the same compose file all will have the same network?

Comment: yes, all the containers will share the same network, but its better to configure the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can either combine the 2 compose files into one, this way all containers will share the same network.

Or you will need to configure the network in both files, here is a simple example.

```
compose 1

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

```
compose 2

networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

This configuration will make network my-network when running docker-comose 1, Then when running docker-compose 2, it will attach the container to the already existing network `my-network`.

You can also, create a network using command line like, `docker network create my-network`

And then add the configuration to the compose files like this

```
networks:
  my-network:
    external:
      name: my-network
```